# Pattern matching function gives error

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Why does the following haskell function gives error ?

The aim is to replicate the given element k number of times in a list and return the list.

Function:

```
--Replicate the element given number of times and return the list.
replicateElement :: (Integral k) => a -> k -> [a]
replicateElement x 0 = error "Cannot replicate Zero times"
replicateElement x 1 = [x]
replicateElement x k = [x] ++ replicateElement(x k-1)
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `k0 -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of `replicateElement'
    Probable cause: `replicateElement' is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `replicateElement (x k - 1)'
    In the expression: [x] ++ replicateElement (x k - 1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: why not return the empty list when `k=0`?

Comment: Liked the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
replicateElement(x k-1)
```

you are passing just 1 argument to `replicateElement`, namely `(x k-1)`, which also means `((x k) - 1)`, and you actually don't intend for `x` to be a function. Instead, what you should write is:

```
replicateElement x (k-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last line should be:

```
replicateElement x k = [x] ++ replicateElement x (k-1)
```

You don't need to put brackets around function arguments in Haskell.